# Angularjs - Can i use a controller to track when all http requests it makes are completed

Tags: angularjs

I have web page interface that has three main blocks. Each block has controllers that make http requests. I want to track the calls for each block so i can unblock the interface for each block when all its calls are completed. I have a $http.interceptor that keeps count of ALL http requests and responses for the page, and can block the page until all requests have been completed, but the client doesnt like this approach.

Any suggestions.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just inject and use [angular's `$q` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and `$q.all(promises)`, which according to the documentation

> combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

You can use code that looks something like this

```
var promiseA = $http.(......);
var promiseB = $http.(......);
var promiseC = $http.(......);
$q.all([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC]).then(function() {
    //do whatever and unblock
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one very simple way to do achieve this would be to set a "block" model on each of those individual controllers until the success of your http request. That eliminates the need for any additional controllers. Example code for inside of one of those controllers:

js

```
$scope.block1Loading = true;
$http
  .get(url)
  .success(function() {
    $scope.block1Loading = false;
  });
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="Block1Controller"
  ng-class="{'blocked': block1Loading}">block 1</div>
```